# Storing files to byte array

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a database object that has a column to store files as `varbinary`. I have tried to store single file using C# and byte arrays and it worked. How can I add multiple files to this column. Please help.

Comment: Create another table and define a 1-many relationship?

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose you'd need to concat the byte arrays from each file into a giant byte array and then insert that byte array into the field, but then how would know where 1 file begins and the next ends?

You could try to put in a magic set of bytes between each file byte array, but then what happens when one of those files randomly has that magic set of bytes?

If the files are the same exact type, say images, you could look for the magic bytes certain image file types always start with to separate them out, but again, there's still the random chance you might find those magic bytes in the middle of one of the files.

There is also memory concerns both saving and retrieving if the combined files are too large.

This idea also violates database design / normalization.

I would do what Jeremy Lakeman recommends: create a child table.

IE,

Files Table Columns:
ParentID (foreign key to parent table)
FileID (Autonumber / primary key)
File (varbinary)

Comment: Thank you for your insights. It is helpful.